# Keeping Track of the Frequencies of a Range of Characters in Multiple Files

Tags: c++

Wondering how to keep count of a range of characters (specifically ASCII 10, and ASCII 32 thru ASCII 126) from many text files. Currently have something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++)
{

    while (!File1.eof())
    {
        data[i] = File1.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }
    while (!File2.eof())
    {
        data[i] = File2.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!words1.eof())
    {
        data[i] = words1.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }


    while (!ST1.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST1.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST2.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST2.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST3.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST3.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST4.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST4.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST5.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST5.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST6.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST6.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST7.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST7.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST8.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST8.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST9.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST9.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!ST10.eof())
    {
        data[i] = ST10.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!chesterton.eof())
    {
        data[i] = chesterton.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }

    while (!dickens.eof())
    {
        data[i] = dickens.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }
    while (!earth.eof())
    {
        data[i] = earth.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }
    while (!mystery.eof())
    {
        data[i] = mystery.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }
    while (!myths.eof())
    {
        data[i] = myths.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }
    while (!simak.eof())
    {
        data[i] = simak.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }
    while (!wodehouse.eof())
    {
        data[i] = wodehouse.get();
        frequencies[i]++;
    }


}
```

The `for` loop goes to 96th element, since there are 96 characters I must keep count of.

`data[]` has been initialized so that `data[0]` is the ASCII 10 character, `data[1]` is the ASCII 32 character, `data[3]` is the ASCII 33 character ... until `data[95]` is the ASCII 126 character.

`frequencies[]` has been initialized to 0 and is the array containing the corresponding count of the ith character in `data[]`.

Should this work?

Comment: How would you do it with one file?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should do this using block reads.

```
const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*1024;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
//...
while (File1.read(&buffer[0], BUFFER_SIZE))
{
    const size_t chars_read = File1.gcount();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < chars_read; ++i)
    {
        frequencies[i]++;
    }
}
```

Memory is always faster to search and access than the hard drive. Hard drives are streaming devices; they work best when kept streaming.  Reading one character at a time has a high incidence of wasted time due to setup.  The ratio of overhead (setup, etc) to data transfer is better with block reads (more data per overhead).

You are not differentiating words or sentences, so there is no concern whether a word or sentence is split across buffer reads.

If you want more performance, you can split this between two threads:  one for reading and the other for processing the data.   You'll also want to use *double buffering* or multiple buffering to reduce the amount of waiting that the processing thread performs.

**Edit 1: After reading**
After you are finished reading, you can print the histogram:

```
for (int i = ' '; i < 127; ++i)
{
    std::cout << i << ": " << frequencies[i] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to keep the data array at all; so if you want to count ascii characters I'd just create a single array of size 128 and directly access it.
so you could do something like that:

```
int main () {

  int frequencies[128] ={};
  std::ifstream is("example.txt"); 
  CountCharacters(is, frequencies);
}
void CountCharacters(std::ifstream &is, int frequencies[])
{
  while (!is.eof())
  {
     char c = is.get();
     frequencies[c]++;
  }
  is.close();
}
```